# WCF Service not connecting to MSSQL

Tags: c#, android, sql-server, linq, wcf

I made a xamarin android app that is supposed to connect to a database. I created a WCF Service that is hosted at a specified address. I then used SLsvcUtil.exe to create a proxy client to call various methods in my service. Previously I had zero issues connecting to the database but after updating my service, it can't even connect to the database. I receive the following error:

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.

The machine that is hosting the database has firewall turned off. The WCF Service is hosted on a seperate machine. I checked to see if mssql is accepting remote connections and it is. I have TCP/IP protocols enabled. I don't know if it will help but I am using LINQ to connect to the database and using visual studio. I can see that with using LINQ to SQL, a connection is seen on my machine (which is hosting the database).

Anyone have an idea?

Comment: Error message is pretty clear, it is not Android or WCF or even LINQ to SQL problem. You need to check only connection between your machine hosting WCF and machine hosting SQL Server. For example check ConnectionString is right.

Comment: Connection string is right. Just not sure how I'm supposed to go about doing this. I'd appreciate it if you could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Nvm, it was connection string, I found the difference in an older file but still don't see how I would know how to alter the connection string to work

Comment: There are huge numbers of resources available for troubleshooting connection string errors.

Answer (score -1):

i did some tests about connecting android apps to wcf, and all my tests fails, i recommended to you to change the approach, use REST api or web API to communicate android device to .NET backend.

Comment: The thing is that it was working completely fine before and I fell like I'm too far in to change my approach now. Thanks though.

Comment: Rearchitecting an entire application to fix a connection string error is not a good approach